# Google Analytic Enhanced eCommerce issue

Tags: google-analytics

No problems with my code(checked with tag assistant as well as analytics debugger). The problem is that I am not seeing product impression data from within analytics. IP filter is disabled, and cookiedomain is set to none.

```
<script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'none');
        ga('require', 'ec');
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

    ga('ec:addImpression', {           
        'id': 'lg1111',
        'name': 'LG Example Product ',
        'category': 'Cell Phones',
        'brand': 'LG',
    });

      ga('set','dimension1', 'exampleSKU'); // REQUIRED Product ID value, e.g., 12345, 67890
      ga('set','dimension2', 'product'); // Optional Page type value, e.g., home, cart, purchase

        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you check your network tab to see if you could see the hit going through with the impression data? I was able to copy and paste your code and see the hit. Bear in mind that data may not show up in your standard reports until it is process, which may take up to 24 hours. Best thing to do is to check with GA Debugger or, again, in the network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A product impression is not the same as a "product view".

Use the add product detail view to register a hit for a product.